# Knockout Master/Detail object from JSON with template and function

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

I've recently started working with Knockout and most things have worked quite easily. However, this one has me a little stumped and was hoping someone could provide some help. I'm creating my Knockout model by serializing a JSON object that has a Master/Detail structure, which I suspect is causing some of my problem. I can bind/render the master portion of the record, and I can bind and render the details using a foreach template. However, in my scenario I want the user to select a detail record to edit from the child list. Problem is I can't get the selection to work. I'm getting the click event to fire and it appears that my detail record is being passed to my event - except that I can't read the value of the properties. Looking in fiddler it appears the object that is coming through is a function call of the event. Not really sure at this point. So, this is my setup

My JSON

```
{
"Height":"250",
"Width":"200",
"Speed":"700",
"Pause":"4",
"ShowItems":"1",
"Animation":"fade",
"MousePause":"true",
"IsPaused":"false",
"Direction":"up",
"DataItems":[{
     "OrderId":1,
     "ItemHtml":"This is item 1"
  },{
     "OrderId":2,
     "ItemHtml":"This is item 2"
  },{"
     OrderId":3,
    "ItemHtml":"This is item 3"
  }]
}
```

Javascript to serialize JSON object

```
var viewModel = {
  vmRotator: ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonObj)

  //-- THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS
  , selectRotatorItem: function (item) {
    //alert(item.OrderId); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    console.log(item);
  }
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

//-- hookup the click event for templated items
$("#rotatorItems").on("click", ".sel", function () {
  var data = ko.dataFor(this);
  viewModel.selectRotatorItem(data); //-- call to object function
});
```

HTML to display the items, provide button to click

```
<table id="rotatorList" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody id="rotatorItems" data-bind="template: { foreach: vmRotator.DataItems }">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20px;">
      <input type="button" class="sel" value="Select" />
      <span data-bind="text: OrderId"></span>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 90%;" data-bind="text: ItemHtml"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Best I can tell this is all working correctly. My event is being called but when I look at the result in the console it looks like the text of a function rather than a value.

In the function:

```
, selectRotatorItem: function (item) {
  //alert(item.OrderId); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
  console.log(item);
}
```

alert(item.OrderId) displays:

```
"function d(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!d.equalityComparer||!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return this}b.r.Wa(d);return c}"
```

Rather than a number like 1 or 2 which is the value of Order ID. Not sure why this is but I've done something wrong.

I've kinda hacked together this code from viewing several examples that are similar to what I'm doing. I could be going about this the wrong way altogether but I think I'm just missing something simple. I'm sure some of the Javascrtipt gods out there can easily see what I don't so I'd appreciate your help.

---

### In response to Rune's answer to my original question, here is the final version that works

Javascript code to build bindings

```
//-- define models: master and detail modesl
var viewRotatorItemModel = {
  'Height': ko.observable(),
  'Width': ko.observable()
};

var viewRotatorModel = {
  'Height': ko.observable(),
  'Width': ko.observable(),
  'Speed': ko.observable(),
  'ShowItems': ko.observable(),
  'Animation': ko.observable(),
  'IsPaused': ko.observable(),
  'Direction': ko.observable(),
  'UseEditor': ko.observable(),
  'HtmlData': ko.observable(),
  'DataItems': {
        create: function (options) {
        return new viewRotatorDataItem(options.data);
      }
    }
};

//-- define objects around models
var viewRotatorDataItem = function (data) {
  var self = this;
  //--> IMPORTANT TO USE fromJS as JSON is already an object
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewRotatorItemModel, self); 
  self.selectItem = function () {
    alert("item with id " + self.OrderId() + " clicked");
  };
};

var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    //--> IMPORTANT TO USE fromJSON as incoming object is JSON text
    ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, viewRotatorModel, self);
};

...
...

//-- create objects when ready
    vmRotator = new ViewModel(jsonObj);
    ko.applyBindings(vmRotator);
```

HTML to display Master/Detail items

```
<h4>Main Items</h4>
<input type="text" id="wc_Height" data-bind="value: vmRotator.Height" />

<input type="text" id="wc_Width" data-bind="value: vmRotator.Width" />

<h3>Detail Items</h3>
<table id="rotatorList" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody id="rotatorItems" data-bind="template: { foreach: vmRotator.DataItems }">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20px;"> 
      <input type="button" value="Select" data-bind="click: selectItem" />
      <span data-bind="text: OrderId"></span>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 90%;" data-bind="text: ItemHtml"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise that you use knockout mapping to add custom functionality to your data items that you can invoke from your markup. (I have created a working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eziwog/1/edit) for you )

Your initial data remains the same and your javascript becomes:

```
var DataItem = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    // add custom functionality to each data item here
    // here an alert is added that can be called via 'selectItem' in markup
    self.selectItem = function(){
      alert("item with id " + self.OrderId() + " clicked");
    }; 
};

var viewModelMapping = {
    'DataItems': {
     create: function(options) {
        return new DataItem(options.data);
        }
    }
};

var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModelMapping, self);
};

var vm = new ViewModel(initialData);
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);   
});
```

And your HTML table becomes (*removed styling for clarity*):

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: DataItems">
  <tr>
      <td">
        <input type="button" value="Select" data-bind="click: selectItem" />
        <span data-bind="text: OrderId"></span>
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: ItemHtml"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can read more about customizing mapped objects in the **Customizing object construction using “create”** and **Customizing object updating using “update”** sections [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Comment: Rune,

Thanks for taking the time to provide such a thorough answer. With some tweaks I got this working now in my code, and I have a much better understanding how/why it works. I also like how it allowed me to clearly define my models. Seems to be a lot of different ways of using Knockout that I am still unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you should drop the jQuery binding for #rotatorItems, and use the 'click' binding on the .sel buttons:

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EKXKF/2/

Main change:

```
<tbody id="rotatorItems" data-bind="foreach: vmRotator.DataItems">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20px;">
      <input type="button" class="sel" value="Select" data-bind="click: $root.selectRotatorItem" />
      <span data-bind="text: OrderId"></span>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 90%;" data-bind="text: ItemHtml"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```